# Distinct MySQL Results

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have the following SQL query:

`SELECT c.comid, d.deid FROM dating_events d JOIN companions c ON d.userid = c.userid WHERE c.userid = 5`

Which Outputs somthing like:

```
-------------
comid | deid
-------------
  2   |   17
  7   |   17
  2   |   18
  7   |   18
```

But what i want it to output is something like this:

```
-------------
comid | deid
-------------
  2   |   17
  7   |   18
```

I tried adding GROUP BY c.comid at the end, it was showing just two results but not quite accurate:

```
-------------
comid | deid
-------------
  2   |   17
  2   |   18
```

I also tried adding the DISTINCT keyword after the SELECT but that wasn't doing anything.

**Edit - Posting Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companions` (
  `comid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `com_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dating_events` (
  `deid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `de_dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Can you provide examples for dating_events and companions tables?

Comment: Thank @unutbu, i was going crazy how to format those SQL Results :)

Comment: @eagerMoose: i'm not sure what kind of examples you want me to post? :(

Answer (score 1):

This should be two separate queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.comid
FROM dating_events d JOIN companions c ON d.userid = c.userid
WHERE c.userid = 5;
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.deid
FROM dating_events d JOIN companions c ON d.userid = c.userid
WHERE c.userid = 5;
```

The reason for that is that apparently 2/17 and 7/18 are not related, so it does not make sense to put them into tuples.  You just have two separate lists of numbers.

Comment: @Peter Eisentraut: why are you saying 2/17 and 7/18 aren't related? because they are :o maybe i'm mis-understanding something :o

Comment: @Zubair1: Well, you haven't given any semantic explanation why you want the 2 next to the 17 and the 7 next to the 18.  So we're just guessing.

Comment: @Zubair1 It looks like you want a list of a user's companions, as well as a list of that user's dating_events. Presumably, these are two separate lists (and should therefore be two separate queries). By trying to get both lists in one query, you end up with every combination of companions to dating_events. If, instead, you're trying to get a list of the user's companions who are also in the user's dating_events, you need to add a clause to account for that relationship.

Comment: @Peter Eisentraut: ahhh, i see :) well i'll try my best to make it more clear, comid (companion id) is created by each user, and deid (dating_event id) is also created by each user but are assign to companions so basically, deid and comid are related, each deid belongs to a comid and each comid belongs to a userid so i am trying to find all the comid and deid for the user=5 but i want both columns to have distinct values in them.

Comment: @Wiseguy, yup, you got it right :). that's exactly what i want to fetch all the companions and dating events for the user but i can't seem to get DISTINCT values for both comid and deid together :(

Comment: @Zubair1 So, if you're just trying to get two lists, they shouldn't be together. They need to be in two separate queries, as Peter suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in two separate queries to get the values you are looking for.

Your example output doesn't really make sense because you're arbitrarily grouping the values of comid and deid together. If you want the distinct values for each column you should just do it in 2 queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.comid
FROM dating_events d 
JOIN companions c ON d.userid = c.userid 
WHERE c.userid = 5

SELECT DISTINCT d.deid 
FROM dating_events d 
JOIN companions c ON d.userid = c.userid 
WHERE c.userid = 5
```

Comment: i'm searching for userid in both C & D which are the same but are = to 5, both C & D tables have the column userid so its easier for me to find out which comid and died belongs to which user. I was planning on running two queries but wanted to try to do this in one query its actually also the first time i'm using a JOIN :o :(